# Marketing Cloud sFTP to vendor issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, ftp, sftp

We are trying to use Marketing Cloud to drop a file onto a vendors sFTP site. We have username and password etc and can make the connection from home, Starbucks or any network except where we work.

Our employer heavily restricts access to network ports, as you'd expect, but our thought was that if we are going to the vendor from SFMC how is the security on our internal network causing the blackout?

Answer (score 0):

The SFTP connection from SFMC is happening directly to the “receiving end”. Hence your local network policies don’t have any impact on this.

To be on the safe side, please ask the vendor to whitelist the FTP IP addresses, which you can [find here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion_on_whitelists.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null). This is probably not an issue in your case, since you can connect to the vendor’s FTP from any other location.